# Sent BCH to a BTC address in my wallet

Tags: cross-chain-recovery

Two days ago, I sent 2.337 BCH from Kraken to Blockchain.info. I cut and paste a BTC address accidentally, not a BCH one. I had used this wallet address about 45 days prior, and so it should be associated with my own BTC wallet, which I have control over.
 (theoretically).

My question then is, how to I get my BCH out of that BTC wallet address on Blockchain.info? I wrote them days ago, and nothing back yet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't possess and control the according private keys, you don't "own" Bitcoins. Maybe you have a right to access and transfer your Bitcoins and maybe legally "you own them", but not technically.

If you have sent BCH to a BTC address, then, only the according private key of that BTC address could help you sending your BCH out of the accidentally used BTC address.

Either you import that private key into a BCH wallet that supports importing private keys or you directly create and sign a raw transaction (experts only).

Blockchain.info could easily do that for you, but I don't expect that highly centralised services will have the man-power to follow such support inquiries.

Also, they could collect the accidentally sent BCH (don't I don't think they do).